# Comprehension list on 3D arrays

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy

I'm manipulating a 3D array of an image of shape

```
(225, 400, 3)
```

I've done this for loop that makes the images black and white:

```
for i in imageArray[:,:,:]:
for x in i:
    if x.mean()<= 100:
        x[:] = 0
    else:
        x[:] = 255
```

But I can't achieve to put it on a comprehension list, I tried it:

```
[0 if x.mean()<=100 else 255 for x in arr_aux[:,:,0:3]]
```

But doesn't make anything

Answer (score 0):

You assign zero to the row, instead of a row of zeros.
Correct:

```
[[0] * len(x) if x.mean()<=100 else [255] * len(x) for x in imageArray[:,:,0:3]]
```